# How do I change which commit the git gutter in IntelliJ is comparing against

Tags: git, intellij-idea

The git gutter in IntelliJ is a good way to see your changes to a file. It compares the current version of the file against the last commit. However, when I commit my changes, the indicators in the gutter disappear.

I want IntelliJ to keep comparing my file against the commit it was originally comparing against, and not update which commit to compare the file to when I make a commit.

How can I specify which commit the git gutter is comparing against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git Scope plugin seems to be very close to what you want, and adds a few more capabilities for comparing to points in the git story: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope/

Comment: Thanks, this seems promising! Will give it a try

Answer (score 2):

The git gutter is there to show uncommitted changes, by comparing your local file to HEAD. This is not configurable. The moment you commit your changes, your commit becomes HEAD, and there's no uncommitted changes to compare anymore, so the gutter cannot highlight any lines.

However, you can use [the *Annotate* action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate) (IntelliJ's name for `git blame`) to show the last commit where each line was introduced and allow a number of actions:

[image]

You might find it useful.

Comment: `git annotate` works really well as a shortcut. I use cmd+§. In IntelliJ go to the keymap in the preferences and search for `annotate` to change it for all VCS.